# Чем отличается анонимная функция от именованной?

Tags: javascript, функции

Понятно что анонимная функция не имеет имени. Есть ли еще какие то отличия кроме указанной? В частности интересует каким контекстом выполнения она владеет кроме своего, а то есть к каким пространствам имен она имеет доступ.

Comment: На самом деле нет анонимных функций, есть анонимные функциональные выражения

Comment: _В частности интересует каким контекстом выполнения она владеет кроме своего, а то есть к каким пространствам имен она имеет доступ._ - эта часть вопроса непонятна

Comment: @Grundy , ну есть внутренне пространство (это ее тело), внешнее (тело функции из которой ее вызвали оно же локальное пространство) и есть глобальное пространство(это тело самого файла где она существует).

Comment: и как это связано с _контекстом выполнения_? :-)

Comment: в двух словах: разницы нет

Comment: все ясно. в книге встретил такие строки. `Анонимная функция здесь используется, чтобы обеспечить передачу локальных переменных, объявленных в ...` . Вот я и задумался в чем разница межу обычной и безымянной функции.

Comment: Зачем тут [tag:javascript-faq]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С точки зрения поведения (*определения `this`, создания замыканий, объявления внутри переменных*) разницы между именованной и анонимной функцией - **нет**.

Если обратиться к [спецификации](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-function-definitions), можно отметить, что функции можно разделить на *FunctionDeclaration* и *FunctionExpression*.

[*FunctionDeclaration* может быть анонимной](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-function-definitions-runtime-semantics-instantiatefunctionobject) только при объявлении ее как `export default`, при этом, при создании объекта функции ей присваивается имя `default`.

Что касается *FunctionExpression*: к именованному *FunctionExpression* можно обращаться в его теле по имени, что позволяет делать рекурсивные вызовы.

Comment: а что значит объявить как `export default` ? я не встречал такого спецификатора.

Comment: @perfect, это относится к модулям: [Использование_экспорта_по_умолчанию](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export#Использование_экспорта_по_умолчанию)

Comment: спасибо за разъяснение